# Updating a value in a particular column and maintaining it throughout the database

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a requirement to substitute a value with some another value and maintain that through out the tables present in the oracle database .

**For example:** *i have a column called city in table tab_a. In city column i can have numerous values of cities and many of the will be repeating.*

So if i change value `"a-> b"` in city column of table `tab_a`, wherever a comes in the city column it should be changed to b.

Now suppose i have another table by the name of `"tab_c"` which has city column.
so if city of column of tab_c table consist of value `"a"` it should also be changed to `"b"`.

Can somebody help me to implement this .

Comment: Please explain better

Comment: Create table for cities, and save `city_id` instead of `city_name` in other tables.

Comment: @fen1x i have to replace city with another city not id

Answer (score 0):

This would be a fine relational desing - you have a `dedicated table with cities`tab_city`with a PK and`city_name`. Other tables use the PK`ID` to reference it.

```
create table tab_a
(id number,
city_id number);

create table tab_b
(id number,
city_id number);

create table tab_city
(id number,
city_name number);
```

A change of city name a signle update of the `city_tab` because the `ID` remains the same.

```
update tab_city
set city_name = 'New York'
where id = 1;
-- 1 record updated, former name  of ID = 1 was "York"
```

Contrary to this, your design identifies the city with the name. This is problematic as for each change you must update all the references.

```
create table tab_a
(city_name varchar2(100));

create table tab_b
(city_name varchar2(100));
```

While performing the updates below, you see immediately the difference to the propper relational design.

```
update tab_a
set city_name = 'New York'
where city_name = 'York';
-- tons of records updated

update tab_b
set city_name = 'New York'
where city_name = 'York';
-- tons of records updated
```